# constructing var name from string concatanation

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm not sure I worded the question correctly.
I have a set of variables, that go like: STO1, STO2, STO3.....STO9; and I need to get the user to input the digit to store and to recall those memory addresses.
So is there a way that the 'STO' be concatenated to the digit (1...9) to get to the var name?
The var names are declared already. I just need to either store a value or retrieve it.
I know that in other languages that is indirect addressing, I think.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Ray.

Comment: Not quite understand your question. Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Why don't you use array/list for this purpose? This is what we usually do when we have a collection of values. Then you can access the specific value with simple: `list[digit]`.

Comment: That's not generally a good idea, and making it happen is a lot of hard work, because the language doesn't really work like that. You could mess around with reflection if you really wanted, but that's usually a sign you're doing something you shouldn't. Why not just store your data in an array or something? instead of ``STO1``, ``myData[0]``

Comment: I guess I could just write a`when`statement and include all of the memory locations (9) and select accordingly, although I wanted to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If variables defined insisde the class (so they are properties) it can be done via Reflection Api.

```
class Example {
    var sto1 = "s1"
    var sto2 = "s2"
}

fun main() {
    val obj = Example()
    val userInput = "1"

    val prop = Example::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "sto$userInput"}
    prop as KMutableProperty<*>
    //get value example
    println(prop.get(obj))

    //set value example
    prop.setter.call(obj, "new value")
    println(prop.get(obj))
}
```

In order to compile it you should add kotlin-reflect lib to your maven/gradle project.

Comment: Wow, I'll have to study that; however I thinks its what i'm looking for. Thanks Nikita.